# Sending an Embed to a different channel (Discord JS)

Tags: javascript, discord, embed, discord.js

I am trying to send an embed to a different channel not to the channel where the command was executed but I am getting an error "Cannot access 'bot' before initialization" I dont know what i did wrong tbh bc ive declared everything on the top of the index.js.

```
 case "alert":
        let text = message.content.replace(prefix + "alert", "")
        const alertembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("**Embed Title**")
        .setDescription(text)
        bot.channels.find("carts").send(alertembed)
        embed.Message.react("")
        embed.Message.react("")
```

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const ms = require("ms")
const fs = require("fs")


var version = "1.0"

const config = require("./config.json")
let prefix = config.prefix;
const token = config.token;

bot.on("ready", () =>{
    console.log("Succesfully started the tools bot");
})

bot.on("message", message=>{

   let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");



   switch(args[0]){
...
```

Comment: I don't think there is enough here to reproduce the problem.  We need a bit more code to show how you are initializing the bot variable.  Also include which Discord.js version as some of this has changed in the latest (namely channels.find).

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I am using 12.1.1 I also tried .get but that did not help aswell

I will try to edit the post with the code on top

Comment: just edited the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, based on the information you've provided I see a few problems, but the error message isn't what I'm expecting for them.  These are certainly issues, but I'm not sure it's **the** issue.

In v12 most collections are replaced by manager objects that contain the collection named `cache`.  This includes message.channels.  So to access the channels cache collection you would need to use:

`message.channels.cache.find()`

This however still has a problem because using find based on a string was deprecated in v11 and removed in v12.  You must pass in a function that returns true if it's what you want.

`bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "carts")`

Update:
One other thing I noticed..
`embed.Message.react("")` 
I don't see a variable named embed.  I think you meant do this from the send.

```
bot.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === "carts").send(alertembed).then(sent => {
    sent.react("")
    sent.react("")
});
```

Comment: Okay thank you can would it be any different if I use the channels Id instead of the name ?

Comment: @MaxiiPaguera Absolutely, if you have the ID then that is the best thing to use.

use ``bot.channels.cache.get(id)`` instead.  However, you still need to handle the promise as I showed in the update I just added above.